# Java Object Reference Passing Vs. C++ Memory Reference Passing

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I understand that Java is pass by value, and that when passing objects into functions, you simply pass the value of the reference to the function/outside its scope.  I know, too, that you cannot alter an object inside a function.  That being understood, can you alter an object whose reference is stored in two different data structures as you could in C/C++?

For example

```
class ObjectReferences {
    static HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    static HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public static void addToBoth(Object o) {
        map1.put("One",o);
        map2.put("Two",o);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer foo = new StringBuffer("wat");
        addToBoth(foo);
        map1.get("One").append("er");
        System.out.println(map2.get("Two").toString());
    }
}
```

By my reasoning this should print out "water".  Can someone explain why this will or will not work in the mystical land of Java?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Not true. The reference is immutable, but the object it points to can be. Strings and integers are immutable, but not all reference types are.

Comment: "I know, too, that you cannot alter an object inside a function." Why can't you?

Comment: For starters, this won't compile because `map1`'s values are `Object`s, not `StringBuffer`s.

Comment: I hope this clears some of your questions [java pass by value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) So if you read through the doc I mentioned, you pass the address location of foo as a value  to the map and so when ever you change the content at the address location of where foo is pointing to your maps map1 and map2 gets updated. Hope this helps

Comment: @nhouser9 -- No I did not try it as I wanted to understand the concepts behind how it worked, not necessarily if it would or wouldn't work, though I probably failed to express that.

Comment: @chrylis -- I was trying for the minimal, generic code that is recommended for examples on SO.  The reason I said that you cannot change them in functions they are passed to, is because I've attempted to add items to a list passed to a function; however no changes to the List were there outside the scope of the function.  I just assumed there was a scoping issue, or something.

Comment: @MarkAndrewRoss Then you need to show code that really does demonstrate the problem you say you're observing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So let's first correct your code so that it works (in Java 7+), and run it:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ObjectReferences {
    static HashMap<String, StringBuffer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    static HashMap<String, StringBuffer> map2 = new HashMap<>();

    public static void addToBoth(StringBuffer sb) {
        map1.put("One",sb);
        map2.put("Two",sb);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer foo = new StringBuffer("wat");
        addToBoth(foo);
        map1.get("One").append("er");
        System.out.println(map2.get("Two").toString());
    }
}
```

This prints `water`, as you expected. Why? Because the `sb` in the `addToBoth` method references the exact same object (the one and only `StringBuffer` first referenced by `foo`), so appending something to it and getting that same object later will return - the same object. Java doesn't magically copy the object internals (unless you clone objects, but that's another story).

Hope that helps.

P.S. you had already almost written the code and were so close to running it yourself. Is there a further background to your question? It seems you could have answered it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  As for why I posted it here was to 1) clear up my understanding of what you can actually do in Java on a conceptual level, and 2) to help any other transitioning C/C++ programmers to learn what they can and cannot do inside functions.  Personally, I'd rather do all of the pointers, referencing, de-referencing, etc. by hand. Plus, I didn't know if the code was considered correct by the community since Java seems to have odd quirks.